# Multiple Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 sql's (each sql is about 10 lines joining about 5 tables). These 2 sqls returns same column. I want to execute sql2 only if sql1 returns no result.

How to do this in one sql?

Comment: Please post up the SQL statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
query1
UNION ALL
( query2
   WHERE NOT EXIST (query1)
)
```

In Oracle you can also factor:

```
WITH conditional_query AS (query1)
SELECT * FROM conditional_query
UNION ALL
( query2 WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT NULL FROM conditional_query) )
```

Comment: well, I end up using coalesce. Thanks for your idea